# C# Linq to entity (EF Core) create SQL statement "like '1 %'" : Startswith doesn't work when passed a variable

Tags: linq, entity, sql-like

I am trying to recreate the SQL condition of: `like '1 %'`.

The column in the table contains two sets of values separated by a space. Using `StartsWith(glassTag)` returns any row where the column starts with '1'. It seems to do a trim on the string before testing the condition.  But, if I use `StartsWith("1 ")`, it returns the rows I expect.

What am I doing wrong?

This is a LINQ to Entity question. `SqlMethods` are not compatible.

the following returns where the Name is: "119 GL-01"

```
        var glassTag = "1 ";
        var gItem = await _context.Items.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(glassTag) && x.Material.MaterialType.Name.Equals("Glass") && x.JobItems.Any(j => j.Job.Code.Equals(pCode))).ToListAsync();
```

The code below returns the results I expect

```
        var gItem = await _context.Items.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("1 ") && x.Material.MaterialType.Name.Equals("Glass") && x.JobItems.Any(j => j.Job.Code.Equals(pCode))).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Please use tags, not text, to tell what you use (also think of the correct version).

Comment: EF Core version, provider used? Everything counts, because this thing Is provider specific and probably you have found bug in provider.

Comment: Try to set var glassTag = @"1 ";

Comment: @Den - got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

StartsWith simply doesn't work for a variable being passed when looking for spaces at the end.

I have captured the sql being generated by EF.

The code below generates the sql directly below it. When passing a variable to the StartsWith condition, it doesn't use "like".  And it creates something that isn't right.

```
var gItem = _context.Items.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(gd.glasstag + " "));


DECLARE @__glassTag_0 nvarchar(4000) = N'1 ';

SELECT [i].[ItemId], [i].[Name]
FROM [Item] AS [i]
WHERE (@__glassTag_0 = N'') OR ([i].[Name] IS NOT NULL AND (LEFT([i].[Name], LEN(@__glassTag_0)) = @__glassTag_0))
```

The code below generates the sql below it.  Note, it uses the "like" condition.

```
var gItem = _context.Items.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("1 "));


SELECT [i].[ItemId], [i].[Name]
FROM [Item] AS [i]
WHERE [i].[Name] IS NOT NULL AND ([i].[Name] LIKE N'1 %')
```

So, I will be creating a stored procedure to retrieve the data I need.  The code will look like this:

```
        var glassTag = gd.glasstag + " ";
        var gItem = await _context.Items.FromSqlRaw($"spItemsByGlassTag '{pCode}', '{glassTag}'").ToListAsync();
```